# Laravel crontab -e is not recognized

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron

This is my first time setting up Cron job and I cannot make it to automatically schedule a command.

So I have a command:

```
public function handle()
{
    $client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features');
$crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.homefeature')->each(function ($node, $key) {
    $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
    $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
    $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
    $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
    $link_r = $link->getUri();
    $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
    $image_s = $image->getUri();
    $filename = basename($image_s);
    $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
    $id = 1+ $key + 1;
    $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
    // if news is null
    if (!$news) {
        $news = new News();
    }
    $news->title = $title;
    $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
    $news->description = $description;
    $news->link = $link_r;
    $news->image = $image_path;
    $news->save();
});
$crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) {
    $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
    $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
    $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
    $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
    $link_r = $link->getUri();
    $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
    $image_s = $image->getUri();
    $filename = basename($image_s);
    $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
    $id = 1+ $key + 1;
    $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
    // if news is null
    if (!$news) {
        $news = new News();
    }
    $news->title = $title;
    $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
    $news->description = $description;
    $news->link = $link_r;
    $news->image = $image_path;
    $news->save();
    $this->info('Scraping done succesfully');
});
}
```

Kernel file:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\NewsScrape'
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('scrape:news')
             ->hourly();
}
```

And I go to a project folder, type crontab -e and I get:

'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

How can this be solved? Please, remember it is my first time using it

Comment: what os do you use ?

Comment: development: windows, production: ubuntu. I will need it for both :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production you must set up the following crontab:

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Be sure to update `/path-to-your-project/` as appropriate.

This will run the `php artisan schedule:run` command every minute which will check to see if any schedulers need running.

I do not know how to set this up for Windows, however I suggest using the development environment [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead), which uses [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It will provide you with a Ubuntu VM, so you can use crontab.

Comment: I did crontab -e and added that file, saved it but when I do crontab -e again it just gives me back new file instead why?

Comment: What editor are you using with `crontab -e`? What console output do you get after closing the editor? You should see `crontab: installing new crontab` after saving and closing the editor

Comment: Yes I have managed to get that far actually however, the cronjob is not running

Answer (score 0):

there is no crontab command on windows, this would work or your production environment but not on windows.

the equivalent is at in command line, type `at /?` to have some help with it, i can't help you with this as i never used it

Comment: do you know how to set it up on ubuntu then? how to use it?

Comment: In ubuntu you can use `crontab -e`