# task sceduler in laravel 5.6 is not repeating as defined

Tags: laravel, task, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I defined a task in laravel. first time that i run 'php artisan schedule:run' it works just fine but task is not repeating. just runs one time. i have no idea what is wrong!

```
$schedule->call(function (){
        $users = User::all();
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $user->type = 'admin';
            $user->save();
        }
    })->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your cron automatically then follow below step:

1) go to your terminal: and run `crontab -e` command.

2) This will open server crontab file, paste below code inside, save it and exit.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Note**: path means your project folder path
(i.e `* * * * * php /var/www/html/yourproject/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`)

Comment: @E.B : Please run crontab -e from your terminal from your project

Comment: @E.B: Please follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519963/laravel-crontab-e-is-not-recognized)

Comment: 'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @E.B: If you using Windows then please follow this link (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows)

Comment: I am using windows and crontab -e is not working on windows. so i have to use windows task scheduler and define a .bat file like the link that you send :). thanks.